# search through the word for the letter which comes alphabetically first, and returns that letter

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write a code that basically requires me to find  the letter that comes alphabetically first and print. Although the printing is required in another function. Need to use the while loop

this what I've gotten so far.

```
def alphabetically_first(word):

    n = 0
    p = 0
    while n + 1 < len(word):
        if word[n] < word[n+1]:
            p = word[n]
        elif word[n + 1] < word [n]:
            p = word[n+1]
        n += 1
    print p 
    return
```

Comment: Please provide the sample input and required output

Comment: This is just an practice of the regular *minimum, maximum* principle. You can find the pseudocode anywhere, please try and apply that.

Comment: Do you mean `min(word)`?

Comment: I also see that he's printing only the last character, since it's indented to outside of `while` loop